# Excisting Joomla Photogallery script: Extract creation date from EXIF (photo) to show on website

Tags: php, date, joomla, exif, photo-gallery

Not sure if this will work, but since Stackoverflow is the best place to ask, here we go:

I got a Joomla CMS installed, added a customized template, added a (paid) photogallery and after all sorts of tweaks the thing is running pretty decent.

The photogallery (component) works in layers. You'll open the website and you'll be in the top layer. Let's say you'll see 4 maps: 2012, 2013, 2014 and 2015. Within those top categories you can add endless sub-categories and in the end, there's the photo's, displayed on individual image-pages.

Example built-up categories:

-Main (home website, basically the top category)

-- 2015 (sub-category)

--- January (sub-category of sub-category)

----- Image.jpg (individual image page located within sub-category January)

The photogallery component consists of a huge amount of files (PHP mostly). Since I'm no PHP-pro (but I do know my way around in small bits), I tried to figure out how the photogallery component works as it comes to reading EXIF data from its photo's.

The idea is to extract the date when the photo was taken from the EXIF-extraction and display it on the individual image-pages.

From what I could find, the EXIF data is being extract with this 'functions' PHP-file. The code-segment: http://pastebin.com/hT40vJnj

Then, there's the PHP-file for the individual image-pages. The next code is being shown beneath each photo and display's a couple of things. The author, some technical stuff (resolution, filetype and filesize) and also there's a mouse-over icon which shows all extracted EXIF-data in a balloon. Even the date which I was talking about to extract and to be able to drop wherever I want: http://pastebin.com/RzbjkP4e

IMAGE: EXIF Balloon (i.stack.imgur.com/S7Njc.png)

The next attempt (which probably is a stupid one) which I already tried didn't work. I simply tried to copy some code from the functions PHP file and tried to mix it up with the next code in the image PHP file:

```
echo '<i style="margin: 0 3px;cursor:default" class="icon-male dgtt-sw" title="'.JText::_('COM_DATSOGALLERY_EXIF_DATETIME').'"></i> '.strftime($ad_datef == 'customdate' ? $ad_datefc : $ad_datef, strtotime($exif_data['DateTimeOriginal'])).'<br />';
        }
```

Again, I mixed some functions PHP code with the original code from the image PHP file, as seen below (this piece of code shows the owner name of the photo on the image page)

```
echo '<i style="margin: 0 3px;cursor:default" class="icon-male dgtt-sw" title="'.JText::_('COM_DATSOGALLERY_INDIVIDUAL_AUTHOR').'"></i> '.$link.'<br />';
        }
```

Is there any simple way to come up with a string/code that I can use to show the date when the photo was taken? Or do I need to dig deeper?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your function is looking just for DateTimeOriginal.
Unfortunately not always this field is provided by the camera.
Other possible fields that you can use instead of DateTimeOriginal are :

- Datetime
- DateTaken
- DateModified
- DateTimeDigitized

To check all the fields you have use var_dump($exif_data);

So to extend the current behaviour you have to modify your EXIF php file replacing the $exif_data['DateTimeOriginal'] if statement (lines 28, 29, 30 in pastebin)  with that :

```
$date = '';
if (isset ($exif_data['DateTimeOriginal']) != '') {
    $date = $exif_data['DateTimeOriginal'];
} elseif (isset ($exif_data['DateTimeDigitized']) != '') {
    $date = $exif_data['DateTimeDigitized'];
} elseif (isset ($exif_data['DateTaken']) != '') {
    $date = $exif_data['DateTaken'];
} elseif (isset ($exif_data['DateModified']) != '') {
    $date = $exif_data['DateModified'];
} elseif (isset ($exif_data['Datetime']) != '') {
    $date = $exif_data['Datetime'];
}

if ($date != '') {
    $dg_exif .= JText::_('COM_DATSOGALLERY_EXIF_DATETIME').': <span>'. strftime($ad_datef == 'customdate' ? $ad_datefc : $ad_datef, strtotime($date)).'</span>';
}
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. I tried to replace the original code (lines 28, 29, 30) in the functions file with yours (the $date to } part), but it didn't had any effect. Since I just mixed things up myself while posting this reply: the previous second Pastebin link (of the image file) was the one with the code I edited (the testing). This is the original code from the iamge file: http://pastebin.com/z7qgRTEu. Was I supposed to try something extra/else? Thanks! ;)

Comment: Hi are you sure is the original one?! Because the line 21 to 25 they look like altered. Note how in the rest of the code there is the $obj syntax and in there no. What happen If you put a echo "test"; in this code? is it displayed in the exif balloon. First of all you should analyse the html of the exif balloon to find the file that generate it and the try to insert something easy, just to be sure you are modifying the right file.

Comment: I copied the entire code from the original image-file to Pastebin now at http://pastebin.com/4Mv7TMh8. The code I mentioned before is at line 374-398. I guess I messed this stackoverflow question a bit up with wrong code, sorry for that. To clearify my question: the information in the balloon is the information that is hardcored in the photo being shown. I'd like the date in that balloon -picture taken- being shown seperatly elsewhere (to be able to put it in a div tag).

Comment: Even when I put back this original file, replacing 28-30 with yours doesn't seem to have any effect (it stays the same). I looked for all references with the word exif through all the files in the component. I put them on Pastebin: datso.functions.php (http://pastebin.com/zGx5XkWr) - libraries\plupload\js\plupload.full.js (http://pastebin.com/TB3nLrt0) - libraries\plupload\js\plupload.full-1.js (http://pastebin.com/KmtmVqzS) - admin\images.datsogallery.php [this is not the same image file as before] (http://pastebin.com/EXNFvseW) - admin\includes\settings.php (http://pastebin.com/SfdSkGW5)